# Why Does The _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font" error show up in my code?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I have write this code:

```
from tkinter import * # Import most of tkinter functions 
from tkinter import messagebox # Import tkinter message box function
from tkinter import colorchooser # Import Tkinter colour chooser
from tkinter.ttk import * # Import Tkinter Progress bar
import time

# Widgets         = GUI elements: buttons, textboxes, labels, images 
# Windows         = Serves as a container to hold these widgets 
# Labels          = An area widget that holds text and/or an image within a window
# Entry Widget    = A Textbox that accepts a single line of user input
# Radio boxes     = Similiar to checkbox but only one can be chosen
# Listbox         = A listing of selectable text items from it's own container


count = 0

File_Start = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\Python Photos\\"

def Add_Food():
    List_Box_Of_Food.insert(List_Box_Of_Food.size(),Food_Add_EnterBox.get())
    Food_Add_EnterBox.delete(0,END)

def Submit_Food(): 
    print("You have ordered "+List_Box_Of_Food.get(List_Box_Of_Food.curselection()))

def Submit_Temp():
    print("The tempature is "+str(Temp_Scale.get())+ " Degrees C")

def Pick_Celeb(): 
    selected_index = z.get()
    print("You picked" + Celeb_Names[selected_index])  

def click_button(): 
    global count 
    count += 1
    print("You have clicked the button "+str(count)+" Times")

def Submit_Username():
    Username = Enter_Box.get() 
    print("You have set your username to: "+Username)
    delete()
    Enter_Box.config(state=DISABLED)

def delete(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END)

def backspace(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(len(Enter_Box.get())-1,END)

def display():
    if (Check_Button_Status.get()==1): 
        print("You agree")
    else: 
        print("You don't agree")

def Click_Username_Box(event):    
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END) 
     
def Click_Food_Box(event):    
    Food_Add_EnterBox.delete(0,END)

def Click_Message_Box_Button(): 
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Even more ultimate GUI!",
                        message="You have found the even more ultimate GUI!")
    #messagebox.warning - (Shows an error symbol)
    #messagebox.error -   (Shows a warning symbol)
    #messagebox.ask -     (Makes an enter box with it's appilications depending on what is put after ask)

def Click_Colour_Button(): 
    User_Chosen_Colour = colorchooser.askcolor()
    User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue = User_Chosen_Colour[1] # We pick index value 0 because the RGB info of the colour is index 0 and the hex value of the colour is in index 1
    print("You picked "+User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue)
    Window.config(bg=User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue)

def Reset_Colour(): 
    Window.config(bg="#ffffff")

def Start_Weather_Check():
    Tasks_Needed_Execute = 10
    for ProgressIndex in range(Tasks_Needed_Execute): 
        time.sleep(1)
        Weather_Bar["value"]+=10


Window = Tk() # Instaniates an instance of a window 

z = IntVar(value=-1)

Elon_Musk_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Elon_Musk(50x28).png")
Jeff_Bezoz_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Jeff_Bezoz(50x28).png")
Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Mark_Zuckerberg_Small(50x30).png")

Fire_Flame_Image = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"FireFlame(50x50).png")
Snowflake_Image = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Snowflake(50x50).png")

Celeb_Photos = [Elon_Musk_Photo, Jeff_Bezoz_Photo, Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo]
Celeb_Names = ["Elon Musk", "Jeff Bezoz", "Mark Zuckerberg"]

for Index in range(len(Celeb_Names)):
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(Window,
                              text=Celeb_Names[Index], # Adds text to radio buttons
                              variable=z, # Groups radio buttons together if they have the same variable
                              value=Index,  # Assigns each single radio button a numerical value
                              font=("Impact",20),
                              image=Celeb_Photos[Index],
                              compound="right",
                              width=250,
                              command=Pick_Celeb) 
    
    radiobutton.place(x=500, y=50+Index*45)

Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Pig2.png") # Converts an regular image into one tkinter can use

Like_Button = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Like-Button2.png")

Window.geometry("900x750") # Changes the dimensions of the Window

Window.title("The Ultimate GUI Program") # Changes the title of the Window

Window.iconbitmap(File_Start+"AngryBird9.ico") # Set icon of the window.


button = Button(Window,
                text="Click me",
                command=click_button,
                font=("Comic Sans,",10,"bold"),
                fg="Red",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="Red", # Activeforeground and activebackground is used to make it so the button does not change colour when pressed
                activebackground="black",
                image=Like_Button,
                compound="bottom") #- Makes it so the button is behind items on it. - This allows the text to be shown and not be covered by the button


button.place(x=50,y=50) # Places the button at x coordinate 50 and at y coordinate 50

Window.config(background="white") # Sets the background colour

#Adding an image and text onto the Window: 


Pig_Label = Label(Window,                                       # Creates a label
              text="You are using the best program ever!", 
              font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
              fg="red",
              bg="white",relief=RAISED,bd=10,
              padx=10,
              pady=10,image=Photo,
              compound="bottom")


Pig_Label.place(x=170,y=170) # Placing the image in a specifed place 

Enter_Box = Entry(Window,font=("Arial"),fg="Black",bg="Gray") 

Enter_Box.place(x=460,y=220)

Submit_button = Button(Window,        # Creates a Button that can submit text into a variable
                       text="Submit",
                       command=Submit_Username)

Submit_button.place(x=700,y=220)

Delete_button = Button(Window,       # Creates a Button that can delete all the text inside the entry box
                       text="Delete",
                       command=delete)

Delete_button.place(x=750,y=220)

BackSpace_button = Button(Window,    # Creates a Button that deletes the most recent character
                          text="Backspace",
                          command=backspace)

BackSpace_button.place(x=795,y=220)  # Places the backspace button at x = 795 and y = 220

Check_Button_Status = IntVar()

Checkbox = Checkbutton(Window,       # Creates a checkbox with text inside  
                       text="I agree to the TOS",
                       variable=Check_Button_Status,
                       onvalue=1,
                       offvalue=0,
                       command=display)

Checkbox.place(x=200,y=100) # Places the checkbox at x = 200 and y = 100

Temp_Scale = Scale(Window,
                   from_=100,to=0, # Sets the highest and lowest value of the scale
                   length=250,
                   font=("Consolas",13),
                   tickinterval=20, # The step for numbers displayed on the side of the scale
                   orient="vertical", # Sets the direction in which the scale goes
                   resolution=0.5, # The increment of the slider values
                   troughcolor="red", # Sets the colour of the user controlled sliding part
                   bg="gray",
                   fg="white") 



Temp_Submit_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Submit tempature",
                            command=Submit_Temp)

Temp_Scale.set((Temp_Scale["from"]-Temp_Scale["to"])/2) # Sets the starting value for the scale (The value the scale will be on without user input). It is calculated to allow it to work if the range is changed

Hot_Label = Label(image=Fire_Flame_Image)
Cold_Label = Label(image=Snowflake_Image)

Hot_Label.place(x=500,y=298)
Cold_Label.place(x=500,y=605)
Temp_Submit_Button.place(x=590,y=350)
Temp_Scale.place(x=480,y=350)


List_Box_Of_Food = Listbox(Window,
                           bg="#f7ffde",
                           font="Constantia",)

List_Of_Food = ["Pizza","Hotdog","Apple","Ham Sandwich"]

for FoodIndex in range(len(List_Of_Food)): 
    List_Box_Of_Food.insert(FoodIndex,List_Of_Food[FoodIndex])

List_Box_Of_Food.place(x=150,y=440)

Food_Submit_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Submit Food",
                            command=Submit_Food)

Food_Add_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Add Food",
                            command=Add_Food)


Food_Add_EnterBox = Entry(Window)
Food_Add_EnterBox.insert(0,"Enter food")
Food_Add_EnterBox.bind("<Button-1>",Click_Food_Box)

Food_Add_EnterBox.place(x=20, y=480)
Food_Submit_Button.place(x=20, y=440)
Food_Add_Button.place(x=20, y=520)

Enter_Box.insert(0,"Enter username") # Puts text inside the entry box (As a place holder in this example)
Enter_Box.bind("<Button-1>",Click_Username_Box) # Removes the text

Message_Box_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Display a new window",
                            command=Click_Message_Box_Button)

Message_Box_Button.place(x=650, y=650)

Colour_Chooser_Button = Button(Window,
                               text="Press me to change the colour of this window",
                               command=Click_Colour_Button)

Colour_Chooser_Button.place(x=650, y=620)

Rest_Colour_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Reset colour",
                            command=Reset_Colour)

Rest_Colour_Button.place(x=650, y=680)

Check_The_Weather_Outside_Button = Button(Window,
                                          text="Check the weather outside",
                                          command=Start_Weather_Check)

Check_The_Weather_Outside_Button.place(x=100,y=200)

Weather_Bar = Progressbar(Window)
Weather_Bar.place(x=100,y=150)

Window.mainloop() # - Displays the window on the computer screen
```

understand making a GUI program however I get the error of _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font" which to me makes no sense becuase no one my items on my GUI seem to be trying to access font where they can not.

How can I fix this?

I know people like to know what you have done beforehand and I myself can not think of anything I can really do with my knowledge than other when I checked my items.

Comment: Without knowing which statement is causing the error it is impossible to guess. Is there no more information in the error message(s)?

Comment: Please try to pare this code down to a [mre]. This will make it easier for us to see where the problem lies, and you may have an easier time finding the issue yourself if you can reduce it down to a single point of failure. If you're getting a specific error message, [edit] your question to include the full traceback here - that error message should tell you exactly which line(s) caused the problem.

Comment: `ttk.Button` doesn't take a font parameter unlike `tk.Button`. This is the reason why `from xxx import *` is discouraged

Comment: Value error occurs in which line of code?

Comment: How do I know which part to shorten this code down to if I don't know where the error is?

Comment: When I do the import - from tkinter.tk import * it just says pylance can not be resolved?