# Why Do I Get The _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font" Error Showing Up In My GUI Program?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I write this code:

```
from tkinter import * # Import most of tkinter functions 
from tkinter import messagebox # Import tkinter message box function
from tkinter import colorchooser # Import Tkinter colour chooser
from tkinter.ttk import * # Import Tkinter Progress bar
import time

# Widgets         = GUI elements: buttons, textboxes, labels, images 
# Windows         = Serves as a container to hold these widgets 
# Labels          = An area widget that holds text and/or an image within a window
# Entry Widget    = A Textbox that accepts a single line of user input
# Radio boxes     = Similiar to checkbox but only one can be chosen
# Listbox         = A listing of selectable text items from it's own container


count = 0

File_Start = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\Python Photos\\"

def Add_Food():
    List_Box_Of_Food.insert(List_Box_Of_Food.size(),Food_Add_EnterBox.get())
    Food_Add_EnterBox.delete(0,END)

def Submit_Food(): 
    print("You have ordered "+List_Box_Of_Food.get(List_Box_Of_Food.curselection()))

def Submit_Temp():
    print("The tempature is "+str(Temp_Scale.get())+ " Degrees C")

def Pick_Celeb(): 
    selected_index = z.get()
    print("You picked" + Celeb_Names[selected_index])  

def click_button(): 
    global count 
    count += 1
    print("You have clicked the button "+str(count)+" Times")

def Submit_Username():
    Username = Enter_Box.get() 
    print("You have set your username to: "+Username)
    delete()
    Enter_Box.config(state=DISABLED)

def delete(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END)

def backspace(): 
    Enter_Box.delete(len(Enter_Box.get())-1,END)

def display():
    if (Check_Button_Status.get()==1): 
        print("You agree")
    else: 
        print("You don't agree")

def Click_Username_Box(event):    
    Enter_Box.delete(0,END) 
     
def Click_Food_Box(event):    
    Food_Add_EnterBox.delete(0,END)

def Click_Message_Box_Button(): 
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Even more ultimate GUI!",
                        message="You have found the even more ultimate GUI!")
    #messagebox.warning - (Shows an error symbol)
    #messagebox.error -   (Shows a warning symbol)
    #messagebox.ask -     (Makes an enter box with it's appilications depending on what is put after ask)

def Click_Colour_Button(): 
    User_Chosen_Colour = colorchooser.askcolor()
    User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue = User_Chosen_Colour[1] # We pick index value 0 because the RGB info of the colour is index 0 and the hex value of the colour is in index 1
    print("You picked "+User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue)
    Window.config(bg=User_Chosen_Colour_HexValue)

def Reset_Colour(): 
    Window.config(bg="#ffffff")

def Start_Weather_Check():
    Tasks_Needed_Execute = 10
    for ProgressIndex in range(Tasks_Needed_Execute): 
        time.sleep(1)
        Weather_Bar["value"]+=10


Window = Tk() # Instaniates an instance of a window 

z = IntVar(value=-1)

Elon_Musk_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Elon_Musk(50x28).png")
Jeff_Bezoz_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Jeff_Bezoz(50x28).png")
Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Mark_Zuckerberg_Small(50x30).png")

Fire_Flame_Image = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"FireFlame(50x50).png")
Snowflake_Image = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Snowflake(50x50).png")

Celeb_Photos = [Elon_Musk_Photo, Jeff_Bezoz_Photo, Mark_Zuckerberg_Photo]
Celeb_Names = ["Elon Musk", "Jeff Bezoz", "Mark Zuckerberg"]

for Index in range(len(Celeb_Names)):
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(Window,
                              text=Celeb_Names[Index], # Adds text to radio buttons
                              variable=z, # Groups radio buttons together if they have the same variable
                              value=Index,  # Assigns each single radio button a numerical value
                              font=("Impact",20),
                              image=Celeb_Photos[Index],
                              compound="right",
                              width=250,
                              command=Pick_Celeb) 
    
    radiobutton.place(x=500, y=50+Index*45)

Photo = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Pig2.png") # Converts an regular image into one tkinter can use

Like_Button = PhotoImage(file=File_Start+"Like-Button2.png")

Window.geometry("900x750") # Changes the dimensions of the Window

Window.title("The Ultimate GUI Program") # Changes the title of the Window

Window.iconbitmap(File_Start+"AngryBird9.ico") # Set icon of the window.


button = Button(Window,
                text="Click me",
                command=click_button,
                font=("Comic Sans,",10,"bold"),
                fg="Red",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="Red", # Activeforeground and activebackground is used to make it so the button does not change colour when pressed
                activebackground="black",
                image=Like_Button,
                compound="bottom") #- Makes it so the button is behind items on it. - This allows the text to be shown and not be covered by the button


button.place(x=50,y=50) # Places the button at x coordinate 50 and at y coordinate 50

Window.config(background="white") # Sets the background colour

#Adding an image and text onto the Window: 


Pig_Label = Label(Window,                                       # Creates a label
              text="You are using the best program ever!", 
              font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
              fg="red",
              bg="white",relief=RAISED,bd=10,
              padx=10,
              pady=10,image=Photo,
              compound="bottom")


Pig_Label.place(x=170,y=170) # Placing the image in a specifed place 

Enter_Box = Entry(Window,font=("Arial"),fg="Black",bg="Gray") 

Enter_Box.place(x=460,y=220)

Submit_button = Button(Window,        # Creates a Button that can submit text into a variable
                       text="Submit",
                       command=Submit_Username)

Submit_button.place(x=700,y=220)

Delete_button = Button(Window,       # Creates a Button that can delete all the text inside the entry box
                       text="Delete",
                       command=delete)

Delete_button.place(x=750,y=220)

BackSpace_button = Button(Window,    # Creates a Button that deletes the most recent character
                          text="Backspace",
                          command=backspace)

BackSpace_button.place(x=795,y=220)  # Places the backspace button at x = 795 and y = 220

Check_Button_Status = IntVar()

Checkbox = Checkbutton(Window,       # Creates a checkbox with text inside  
                       text="I agree to the TOS",
                       variable=Check_Button_Status,
                       onvalue=1,
                       offvalue=0,
                       command=display)

Checkbox.place(x=200,y=100) # Places the checkbox at x = 200 and y = 100

Temp_Scale = Scale(Window,
                   from_=100,to=0, # Sets the highest and lowest value of the scale
                   length=250,
                   font=("Consolas",13),
                   tickinterval=20, # The step for numbers displayed on the side of the scale
                   orient="vertical", # Sets the direction in which the scale goes
                   resolution=0.5, # The increment of the slider values
                   troughcolor="red", # Sets the colour of the user controlled sliding part
                   bg="gray",
                   fg="white") 



Temp_Submit_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Submit tempature",
                            command=Submit_Temp)

Temp_Scale.set((Temp_Scale["from"]-Temp_Scale["to"])/2) # Sets the starting value for the scale (The value the scale will be on without user input). It is calculated to allow it to work if the range is changed

Hot_Label = Label(image=Fire_Flame_Image)
Cold_Label = Label(image=Snowflake_Image)

Hot_Label.place(x=500,y=298)
Cold_Label.place(x=500,y=605)
Temp_Submit_Button.place(x=590,y=350)
Temp_Scale.place(x=480,y=350)


List_Box_Of_Food = Listbox(Window,
                           bg="#f7ffde",
                           font="Constantia",)

List_Of_Food = ["Pizza","Hotdog","Apple","Ham Sandwich"]

for FoodIndex in range(len(List_Of_Food)): 
    List_Box_Of_Food.insert(FoodIndex,List_Of_Food[FoodIndex])

List_Box_Of_Food.place(x=150,y=440)

Food_Submit_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Submit Food",
                            command=Submit_Food)

Food_Add_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Add Food",
                            command=Add_Food)


Food_Add_EnterBox = Entry(Window)
Food_Add_EnterBox.insert(0,"Enter food")
Food_Add_EnterBox.bind("<Button-1>",Click_Food_Box)

Food_Add_EnterBox.place(x=20, y=480)
Food_Submit_Button.place(x=20, y=440)
Food_Add_Button.place(x=20, y=520)

Enter_Box.insert(0,"Enter username") # Puts text inside the entry box (As a place holder in this example)
Enter_Box.bind("<Button-1>",Click_Username_Box) # Removes the text

Message_Box_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Display a new window",
                            command=Click_Message_Box_Button)

Message_Box_Button.place(x=650, y=650)

Colour_Chooser_Button = Button(Window,
                               text="Press me to change the colour of this window",
                               command=Click_Colour_Button)

Colour_Chooser_Button.place(x=650, y=620)

Rest_Colour_Button = Button(Window,
                            text="Reset colour",
                            command=Reset_Colour)

Rest_Colour_Button.place(x=650, y=680)

Check_The_Weather_Outside_Button = Button(Window,
                                          text="Check the weather outside",
                                          command=Start_Weather_Check)

Check_The_Weather_Outside_Button.place(x=100,y=200)

Weather_Bar = Progressbar(Window)
Weather_Bar.place(x=100,y=150)

Window.mainloop() # - Displays the window on the computer screen
```

But I get this error when trying to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Python Projects\3GUI.py", line 100, in <module>
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(Window,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1022, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::radiobutton", kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 527, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2648, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font"
```

And whenever I try to fix by removing the unknown option it keeps just saying there is a new unknown option and it seems like it would happen until there are no items left on the GUI at all.

I would of cut down the code to a spefic part however I don't where the error is, all I know is that where it says the unknown option is on line 100.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked 2 days ago [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142428/why-does-the-tkinter-tclerror-unknown-option-font-error-show-up-in-my-code)? In the comments someone already pointed out the likely cause.  Don't use wild card imports and you wont confuse a `ttk` widget with a standard one.

Comment: I have made a new post to make my issue easier to understand because there were a lot of edits I needed to do to my post and I thought it would be easier to start from strach. I also asked a question in the last post and I fix it didn’t work but if I did something wrong please tell me

Comment: To fix your problem you need to eliminate your wilcard imports which means DO NOT use `from tkinter import*` or `from tkinter.ttk import*` that is what is causing your issue.  Instead use `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import ttk`. Then go back through your code and prefix every standard tkinter widget with `tk` for example `button = tk.Button` and then when you want to use a `ttk widget` prefix it with `ttk` for example `Weather_Bar = ttk.Progressbar`.

Comment: Thank you that it explained it very well I will try it and get back to you however can you explain why a wildcard import exists if it is causing these problems. Is there some other use?

Comment: @Underflow, you can read [This explanation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports:~:text=Wildcard%20imports%20(,interfaces%20still%20apply.))  Wildcard imports have their uses, even to just quickly write a script for testing but if your goal is to write code that is both easy to read and debug you should avoid them.